# Why is the JQuery hotkeys triggering more than once for shortcut

Tags: jquery, hotkeys, jquery-hotkeys

I have the following code:

each shortcut is for different functionality, but when I use ctrl+r it displays the alert 4 times. Am I doing anything wrong? the code below looks fine for me...

I'm using chrome, but I don't think it matters

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+r', function (event) {
    alert("should be only once");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+1', function () {
    //other code
    return false;
});

$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+2', function () {
    //other code
    return false;
});

$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+3', function () {
    //other code
    return false;
});
```

Edit:
I am using Hotkeys JQuery plugin

Comment: What happens if you use keyup?

Comment: could you provide me a link to documentation where `$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+3'` is proper syntax?

Comment: @f01 it doesn't override the regular browser functionality for ctrl+ *

Comment: @Peter, I found it  in SOF for binding with ctrl

Comment: OK so I believe you are using `jquery.hotkeys.js` plugin right?

Comment: I can't find it, I'm searching for you. Yes I am using hotkeys jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the JS isn't being called multiple times. You can unbind(...) it inside the callback function to see if that is what's happening.